# not able to resolve AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3 and working on an ML project. My code ran fine for the first time but suddenly, out of nowhere, this error popped up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-2-3ae66814e4b2>", line 1, in <module>
import pandas as pd

File "C:\Users\ruhani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
from pandas.core.api import *

File "C:\Users\ruhani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper

File "C:\Users\ruhani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 49, in <module>
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

File "C:\Users\ruhani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 67, in <module>
from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs

File "C:\Users\ruhani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 36, in <module>
trainDF=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\ruhani\\Desktop\\Minor Project\\projects\\train.csv\\train.csv")

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

Please help me as I am new to Python and Machine Learning.

Comment: Do you have a file called `pandas.py` in your working directory?

Comment: You are getting into train.csv twice, do you doubt that looping ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nope

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan No doubts in that. It is the path of csv file, first one represents the directory name.

Comment: @AnkushSoni, you must have pandas.pyc file atleast in your working directory. I am quiet sure you must have

Comment: @ChetanVasudevanI'm sorry but I'm not able to figure out which file is it. In the directory in which I have my project, I have only .py file.